# Unverified transaction with 78 confirmations

Tags: transactions

Transaction is here...

8aa341eb0f0fdea739b27bdbe29c47407de342c9debb2093cde16d13fcce05d8

One of the inputs has 93 confirmations but is unverified...

ab56917add395f61da4599cedcfa785274ea81677aefb72a2d4dfd896742504a

Is this going to resolve itself or is there some action I need to take?

Using Electrum wallet.

Comment: That sounds like a bug in Electrum. Transactions that are confirmed cannot have unconfirmed inputs.

Answer (score 1):

All the inputs seem to be verified. (At 2017-05-24 13:58:05.)

You cannot have a confirmed transaction with unconfirmed input.

There might be an issue with your Electrum wallet that displays something else, I cannot help you with that, since I don't use Electrum. However, right now, everything seems to be confirmed.

Comment: Thanks. I just generated from seed on another machine and it looks fine/spendable. So now just wondering why these transactions are still displaying the number of confirmations ticking up on blockchain.info. All my older transactions no longer display confirmation numbers?

Comment: Are you asking about Electrum, or about blockchain.info? Confirmations always increase all the time.